# The proof of isomorphism between the double complex and the de-Rham cohomology (Theorem 8.1 - Bott and Tu)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Theorem 8.1 of this book says the isomorphism
\begin{equation}
H_D(C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*))\simeq H_\text{dR}^*(M).
\end{equation}
In this proof we consider a map
$r:\Omega^*(M)\rightarrow\Omega^*(U)\oplus\Omega^*(V)\subset C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$.
This induces a map in cohomology:
$r^*: H_\text{dR}^*(M)\rightarrow H_D^*(C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*))$.

A $q$-cochain $\alpha\in C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$ has two components,
$\alpha = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1$, where $\alpha_0\in K^{0,1}$ and $\alpha_1\in K^{1,q-1}$.
The exactness of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence gives $\exists\beta$ s.t.
$\delta\beta = \alpha_1$.
Then $\alpha - D\beta$ has only the $(0,q)$-component.

We need to prove that $r^*$ is an isomorphism.
To prove $r^*$ is injective, suppose $r(\omega) = D\phi$ for some cochain $\phi\in C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$.
By writing as $\phi = \phi' + D\phi''$, where $\phi'$ has only the top component,
\begin{equation}
r(\omega) = D\phi' = d\phi'.
\end{equation}

I thought the "top component" means $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\in K^{0,*}$ and $\delta\alpha = 0$.
Then the above equality is obtained.
Tell me if my thought is incorrect..

P.S. Later in Proposition 8.8
$r(\omega) = D\phi$ with $\phi$ has only the top component.
The book says $\delta\phi = 0$. How to obtain this conclusion?